# C# Dictionary<int,Object> updates by itself

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety

I'll try to resume everything as much as possible:

I have a class that creates a dictionary (let's call it secondary dictionary) with the initial values of some of the elements of another dictionary, (for simplicity, let's call it the main dictionary and this class does this only once) and then a thread that checks every x miliseconds against this main dictionary, that's being regularly updated every y miliseconds, for any changes on the elements that where stored in the initialization phase.

My problem is, that when I want to compare the values of element1 in the main dictionary against the value of element1 in the secondary dictionary, they're always the same, (I undersatnd that, until the main dictionary is nnot updated, both values will be the same, but when the main dictionary gets updated, so does the second, immediately, without me doing anything)

I've tried ConcurrentDictionaries, using locks, a combination of boths, creating a new element in the initialize functions instead of passing it directly, but nothing seems to work

```
class Checker
{
    private static bool secondaryDictionaryHasChanged = false;
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, ValueDTO> secondaryDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ValueDTO>();

    public Checker()
    {
        initSecondaryDictionary();

        Thread checkChangedValsThread = new Thread(() => checkChangedValsThreadFunction(1000));
        checkChangedValsThread.Start();
    }

    public void initSecondaryDictionary()
    {
        Object MainLock = new Object();
        lock (MainLock)
        {
            Object secondaryLock = new Object();
            lock (secondaryLock)
            {
                foreach (var variable in Maindictionary)
                {
                    if (variable.isElegibleValue)
                    {
                        ValueDTO ValueDTOToAdd = new ValueDTO();
                        ValueDTOToAdd.EligibleVar = variable;

                        if (variable.contextVariables.Count > 0)
                        {
                            List<Var> contextVariablesToAdd = new List<Var>();
                            foreach (var item in variable.contextVariables)
                            {
                                contextVariablesToAdd.Add(getVarFromMainDictionary(item));
                            }
                            ValueDTOToAdd.ContextVars = contextVariablesToAdd;
                        }
                        secondaryDictionary.TryAdd(ValueDTOToAdd.EligibleVar.varCode, ValueDTOToAdd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        secondaryDictionaryHasChanged = false;
    }

    public void checkChangedValsThreadFunction(int checkTime)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!secondaryDictionaryHasChanged)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(checkTime);

                    Object mainLock = new Object();
                    lock (mainLock)
                    {
                        Object secondaryLock = new Object();
                        lock (secondaryLock)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in secondaryDictionary)
                            {
                                ValueDTO secondaryDictionaryDTO = item.Value;
                                Var variableInSecondary = secondaryDictionaryDTO.EligibleVar;

                                Var variableInMain = getVarFromMainDictionary(item.Value.EligibleVar.varID);

                                int valueInMain = variableInMain.getIntValue();
                                int valueInSecondary = variableInSecondary.getIntValue();

                                if (valueInMain != valueInSecondary)
                                {
                                    //IT NEVER ENTERS THIS HERE
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Some exception: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class ValueDTO
{
    public Var EligibleVar { get; set; }
    public List<Var> ContextVars { get; set; }
}

internal class Var
{
    public int varCode { get; set; }
    public string varID { get; set; }

}
```

I add a reduced version of the code I have the thing is that it will never go inside that `if(mainValue != secondaryValue)`

any help or info about where I'm going wrong will be deeply appreciated

Comment: You have two Dictionaries that both point to the same instances of objects for the same key. That's why you are actually _not_ comparing A to B but A to A, which is of course always the same.

Comment: Please, take a look on how reference type works.

Comment: I agree with @Fildor. Quick explaination: You do not have the objects themselves in the dictionaries but instead just a reference to the address where the "real" object is. 
Imagine a reference like a "address to a house" being on a sheet of paper. When you recolor the house (your object), everyone who has a paper with the address (reference) of the house will see the changed color ;-).

If you want them to see different colors, you'll need two houses (two objects) and some more papers with the new address (reference to the new house)

Comment: There are some other issues with this code. 1. Locks need to be given a object you want exclusive access to (or a object representing a shared resource). Creating an non-shared object and locking it does nothing. 2. If you want to do something ever X seconds, use a timer instead of sleeping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) already said, you have one object and two references to it.
To simplify your problem I created a short sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    class Person
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var myPerson = new Person();
        myPerson.Name = "User1";
        var list1 = new List<Person>();
        var list2 = new List<Person>();
        // put a reference to myPerson into each of the lists
        list1.Add(myPerson);
        list2.Add(myPerson);
        // get the reference to myPerson from list1
        var myPersonInList1 = list1[0]
        myPersonInList1.Name = "User2";
        // this will print User2 because there is only one person object         
        Console.WriteLine(list2[0].Name);
    }
}
```

Basically no matter where you pass the `Person`, it will always be a reference to the `Person` instance you created. All changes to it will apply to the object behind the reference. All references point to the same object.

---

**Disclaimer**: The following explanation is far from complete and not entirely true in all cases.

A bit more in depth knowledge very simplified, but I hope you'll get the point.
There is a stack and a heap storage. The stack contains value types and references and the heap contains objects.

Stack:

```
Variable | Value

--------------------
myPerson | @abc123
list1[0] | @abc123
list2[0] | @abc123
myInt    | 42
```

Heap:

```
Address  | Value
-------------------
abc123   | { Name: "User2" }
```

Now every time you create a variable pointing to `myPerson`, you only create a new entry in the stack, pointing to the same object in the heap. Now, of course when you update the object behind the reference and set its name to "User1", all references will display the change.

Every time you invoke a constructor via `new`, you'll create a new entry in the heap storage and a reference in the stack to it (the variable holding the newly created object).

As soon as no entry in the stack references a certain entry in the heap anymore, the object from the heap is deleted (also known as garbage collection)